# Why do we assume T(n-1)=T(n-2) for Time Complexity of Fibonacci series?

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory, fibonacci

For recursive implementation of Fibonacci series, the recursive equation is given by:-

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c
```

My question is that why do we have to assume that upper bound of T(n-2) has to be T(n-1) and similarly why lower bound of T(n-1) has to be equal to T(n-2)?

Suppose some recursive equation is given as:-

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) + T(n-5) + c
```

then would we be assuming here also that upper bound of T(n-2) and T(n-3) will be equal to T(n-5) and lower bound of T(n-3) and T(n-5) will be equal to T(n-2) ,i.e.,

For approximating upper bound, `T(n) = 3T(n-5) + c`

and for approximating lower bound, `T(n) = 3T(n-2) + c`

in order to solve for T(n) ?

Comment: The recurrence is strictly decreasing to its a given that T(n - 1) >= T(n - 2)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. In what sense do we assume the upper bound of T(n-2) has to be T(n-1) and so on? The equation T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c does not include any upper bounds.

Comment: You can't in general assume that T is increasing, so any assumption that it is needs to be justified. For fibonacci it's clear, since part of computing fib(n+1) (using the obvious recursive code) involves computing fib(n), so must take longer.

Comment: The runtime of the collatz function is one that is not a decreasing function.